# '28' Out of Stack Space. Worksheet_Change and Application.ScreenUpdating

Tags: vba, excel, stack-overflow

thanks in advance for any clarity you can offer.

In an Excel Workbook with many modules and worksheets, at the bottom of the VBA code for SHEET2, there is this Subroutine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim TargetCells As Range

Set TargetCells = Range("B1000:B1029")

If Not Application.Intersect(TargetCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
   Call SpecificSubRoutine
End If

End Sub
```

My understanding of this code is that it watches the entire sheet for ANY changes. If ANYTHING is changed, anywhere on the sheet, it runs the If statement. The If statement fails in the event that any of the changes made to the sheet take place outside of the specified `TargetCells` range, but this Sub still tries to validate the If statement EVERY time ANYTHING is changed on the sheet.

Now, you might be able to guess that my problem is some stack overflow. (Run-time error '28': Out of Stack Space)

Whenever the `Worksheet_Change` Sub runs, if the changes to the sheet were made inside of the `TargetCells` range, it calls `SpecificSubRoutine` which populates cells, which triggers the `Worksheet_Change` Sub for every time `SpecificSubRoutine` populates ANY cell. (`SpecificSubRoutine` also calls different modules, which of course populate cells, which of course trigger the `Worksheet_Change` Sub)

Not so good.

Also, most of the subroutines throughout the application are wrapped in `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` / `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`, which I mistakenly thought would limit the number of times  `Worksheet_Change` is called to once, immediately after `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` runs.

**NOTE OF IMPORTANCE:** *Neither `SpecificSubRoutine` nor any of the Subroutines called by it populate cells in the `TargetCells` range.* I'm not quite that dim...

Here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to narrow the scope of what triggers the `Worksheet_Change` Sub, so that only changes in the `TargetCells` range triggers it? (instead of changes anywhere in the sheet)
2. Is there a way to do what I mistakenly thought that `Application.ScreenUpdating` would do? (make changes to the sheet all in one bulk update, as opposed to triggering a change with nearly every step)
3. Also, as an extra curiosity, is there a way to have `Worksheet_Change` watch 2 specific ranges (instead of the whole sheet?) Knowing how to do this would be paramount, and would likely solve all of the problems on this sheet.

My intuition is to add an `End` to the last part of `SpecificSubRoutine`, or to the end of any/all of the Subroutines called by it, but I'm just not sure this will circumvent the looping through `Worksheet_Change` multiple times, since `Application.ScreenUpdating` doesn't bulk update like I thought.

Ideas?

Comment: add `Application.EnableEvents=False` in the beggining of `Worksheet_Change` and `Application.EnableEvents=True` in the end

Comment: @simoco, this is a great pointer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 1: No  - the event handler responds to all changes on the sheet: any filtering in how you respond to that change must occur in the handler itself.

Part 2: answered by @simoco

Part 3 (and incorporating simoco's suggestion):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents=False

    If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("B1000:B1029"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       Call SpecificSubRoutine
    End If

    If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("D1000:D1029"), Target) Is Nothing Then
       Call SomeOtherSpecificSubRoutine
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Aside from the extra closing parens, this works as I'd like it to, thanks Tim. I wonder if there is any way to declare an event handler for a range, like: `A1_Change` instead of `Worksheet_Change`.

Comment: That is covered in the "part 1" of my answer.

Comment: Right, I read "part 1", because I completely cherish every response I get on this site. I'm sure it makes perfect sense to someone lucky enough to know VBA well, but to me, "filtering in how you respond to that change must occur in the handler itself" doesn't make any sense. Are you talking about altering the `ByVal Target As Range` part to watch a certain range? I'm currently studying up on event handlers, so if this is an open-ended question, I might be able to find the answer soon on my own.

Comment: How you decide what action to take (if any) is shown in Part3 - you need to check the provided range `Target`, which represents the range in which a change triggered the `Worksheet_Change` Sub.